# Read merged cells in HTML table row by row, or column by column

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I have a table like this:

[image: a table with merged rows]

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.corner {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><td class="corner"></td><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr></thead>
  <tr><th>1</th><td rowspan="3">A1:A3</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td><td>D1</td></tr>
  <tr><th>2</th><td>B2</td><td>C2</td><td>D2</td></tr>
  <tr><th>3</th><td>B3</td><td>C3</td><td>D3</td></tr>
  <tr><th>4</th><td>A4</td><td>B4</td><td>C4</td><td>D4</td></tr>
  <tr><th>5</th><td rowspan="2">A5:A6</td><td>B5</td><td rowspan="2" colspan="2">C5:D6</td></tr>
  <tr><th>6</th><td>B6</td></tr>
</table>
```

If I try to read column C using `table.rows[row_index].cells[3]` I get the cells [C, C1, D2, D3, C4, C5:D6], but I want to get [C, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5:D6]. Similarly, if I try to read row 6 I get just [6, B6], but I want to get [6, A5:A6, B6, C5:D6]. A two-dimensional array (matrix) with dimensions equal to those of the table, where merged cells exist at multiple indices, would be ideal.

I looked for a DOM API to get the displayed starting row/column of a cell, but was unable to find anything useful. There are accessors for the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes, which default to 1 and parse the attribute as a number. Using `table.rows[y].cells[x]` does make handling different sections like `thead` and `tbody` easier than querying the elements directly.

I did find that there is [a specification for how to place cells into slots](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#forming-a-table), used internally in browsers. While it did describe the ground truth for how to determine what I was looking for, it also deals with correcting errors HTML authors make and lots of other unnecessary details for my use case.

How can I construct a 2D array where each row/column pair maps to the cell displayed there?

Answer (score 1):

The `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes span only in the iteration order of `row.cells` and `table.rows` respectively. Because of this we can fill the first available space in a row using the very array we are constructing.

This method does not pad out the array with null values in case of a malformed table with missing or extra cells.

```js
function getTableSlots(table) {
  const slots = []
  for(const row of table.rows) {
    for(const cell of row.cells) {
      let x = cell.cellIndex, y = row.rowIndex
      while(slots[y] && slots[y][x]) x++
      for(let dx = 0; dx < cell.colSpan; dx++) {
        for(let dy = 0; dy < cell.rowSpan; dy++) {
          while(y+dy >= slots.length) slots.push([])
          slots[y+dy][x+dx] = cell
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return slots
}

const slots = getTableSlots(document.querySelector("table"))

// Format for snippet console
console.log(`[
  ${slots.map(row => {
    return JSON.stringify(row.map(cell => cell.textContent.padEnd(5)))
  }).join(",\n  ")}
]`)
// For real console
console.log(slots)
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.corner {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr><td class="corner"></td><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th></tr></thead>
  <tr><th>1</th><td rowspan="3">A1:A3</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td><td>D1</td></tr>
  <tr><th>2</th><td>B2</td><td>C2</td><td>D2</td></tr>
  <tr><th>3</th><td>B3</td><td>C3</td><td>D3</td></tr>
  <tr><th>4</th><td>A4</td><td>B4</td><td>C4</td><td>D4</td></tr>
  <tr><th>5</th><td rowspan="2">A5:A6</td><td>B5</td><td rowspan="2" colspan="2">C5:D6</td></tr>
  <tr><th>6</th><td>B6</td></tr>
</table>
```